# Firestore: Document parent name lacks "/"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using jest to perform integration tests to firestore. I expected to receive document consisting of fields equal to field1 and field2. However, I have received the below error instead.

I have tried creating a composite index in firecase console but the problem still persists. This situation seems to only happen during testing as the code works fine when I run the Node.js app normally. I have narrowed the error to come from the code below:

```
const response = await fs.collection('collection1').where('field1', '==', field1).where('field2', '==', field2).get();
```

The error message is as such:

```
Error: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Document parent name "projects/int-test-1-5tb01cf1-poiu-0qa8-lk87-e1aeff685f2d/databases/(default)" lacks "/" at index 76.
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re firebase tools have just updated from 6.9 to 7.0.

This is a breaking change in version 7.

We fixed it by setting the max version to 6.9. I’ll find the line to set the version... one sec.

So we use a script for our tests and the line in the script is...

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g firebase-tools@6.9.2
```

You should be able to set 6.9.2 as your max version of firebase tools to fix this.

Comment: Any idea what the breaking change was or if there's a way to use the newer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the package @firebase/testing to version 0.11.8 (matching up with firebase-admin 8.3.0) and running the 7.2.0 version of the emulator fixed this issue for me.