# Unable to get documents for a collection in fire cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This really feels completely strange to me. It worked perfectly fine almost 1 week back but now it keeps throwing error:

> error.ts:166 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Document name "["projects/anilproject12001/databases/(default)/documents/1234/J9a7qpOGHjfCBoXzRu6P"]" lacks "projects" at index 0.

I have configured a very simple db structure, which looks like below:
[My cloud firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN1Bp.png)

And my code looks like below:

```
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  //var db = firebase.database().ref('test1');
  var db = firebase.firestore();


  db.collection("1234").doc().get().then(function(){console.log('success!');})
```

Any idea why is this happenning? I have deleted the previous DB and made the simplest of entries for debugging purpose.
Is there something that I am missing in configuration?

Comment: Might be related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658105/firestore-document-parent-name-lacks). Have you tried updating firebase-admin and firebase-tools?